# If we make any change in view of a table, will it change the actual table data?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

If we make any change in view of a table, will it change the actual table?
If we do update or delete on a view of table will it change the value of the actual table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will (for non read only view).

If you create the view with `READ ONLY` option, then you can not change it.

The simple conclusion is:

**If you could make change to a view, then it will change the actual table, if the view is not updatable, then you can't make change to it.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will. Depending on the view it will fail or not. Usually views with joins will fail since it doesn't know how to change it and in what order.

If it's just a single table, non-aggregated view it will always be able to insert/update/delete.

As [Nicholas Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nicholas-krasnov) commented:

> If it's a key preserved "view with joins" it will still allow for a base table (row appears at most once) be updatable.